# Need to use JS to insert links in a custom block for Colorbox to use but $scripts have to be called in <head>. How to delay Colorbox JS?

Tags: javascript

I have a custom block where links are generated by jQuery (or vanilla JS) based on which panel panes are on a page. Users can use IPE so the links need to be dynamically created.

However, because $scripts is called in the head, Colorbox has already run, found the classes and done its thing meaning my new Colorbox links open as regular links killing my functionality.

Is there any way around this? Can I delay the Colorbox JS and run it in the footer?

Comment: Rather than delay, have you tried `Drupal.attachBehaviors('#block-id');` after you've dynamically created the links?

Comment: @Clive, going from your post, I ended up using Drupal.behaviors and it works. Thanks for the lead!